# zend framework 2 fatal error after add module

Tags: php, localhost, zend-framework2

I install ZF2 on my localhost and then I test the public page and it is work.
I tried to download a module [MwopGuestbook](https://github.com/EvanDotPro/MwopGuestbook) and then zend show me an error:

```
Fatal error: Interface 'Zend\Module\Consumer\AutoloaderProvider' not 
found in D:\xampp\htdocs\zend\module\MwopGuestbook\Module.php on line 8
```

How can we solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like outdated code there, I'm guessing that's an early incarnation of the `Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\*` implementations

If it is, you can try changing the first 7 lines in MwopGuestbook/Module.php to the following...

```
<?php

namespace MwopGuestbook;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;

class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface
{
```

It should solve the complaints about not finding the interface, no guarantees there aren't other parts of that code using outdated calls though :-/

Comment: Now I get an error: "
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (Consumer) could not be initialized.' in D:\xampp\htdocs\zend\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php:140 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\zend\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php(81): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModule('Consumer')...... "

Comment: #1 [internal function]: Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->onLoadModules(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\zend\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(460): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))

Comment: #3 D:\xampp\htdocs\zend\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(204): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('loadModules', Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent), NULL) #4 D:\xampp\htdocs\zend\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php(100): Z in D:\xampp\htdocs\zend\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php on line 140

Comment: Do you actually have a module named `Consumer` in your module or vendors folder? Or did you perhaps try adding Consumer to the list of modules to load in your application.config.php to see if it fixed the issue you were having to begin with? If so, remove Consumer from the list of modules in application.config.php